# Round function guaranteed to generate the best floating point approximation?

Tags: javascript, python, floating-point

When I run `round(3.12143345454353,2)`, am I guaranteed to get the same floating point approximation (3.12000000000000010658141036401502788066864013671875
) that I get when I use the `3.12` literal?

In other words, is round(3.12143345454353,2)===3.12 going to be true? Is it true in general, so if x rounds to y does the floating point arithmetic guarantee that round(x,k)===y?

Comment: I suggest you to add the tag of the language you are using. Javascript?

Comment: I don't think there is any guarantee, no.  It's virtually never safe to use `==` with floating point numbers.

Comment: "if x rounds to y does the floating point arithmetic guarantee that round(x,k)===y" Isn't that a tautology? (You need to add a language tag though, and possible say on what device/compiler/interpreter/... you are running)

Comment: C does not even guarantee that `1.23` and `1.230` have the same value (unless this is changed in C 2023). C 2018 note 77 to 6.4.4.2 5 says “`1.23`, `1.230`, `123e-2`, `123e-02`, and `1.23L` are all different source forms and thus need not convert to the same internal format and value.” This permissiveness us due to the complexity of handling all the rounding that occurs in calculations parsing things like `123456789…123456789e-100` and `1.23456789…123456789`. If parsed with correct rounding as specified by IEEE-754, the results will be the same.

Comment: @David Vonka, "In other words, is round(3.12143345454353,2)===3.12 going to be true? " --> No.  Post the definition of the `round(x,i)` function for details.

Comment: This depends on the implementation of `round`, but if it is correctly rounded, then yes, assuming that your definition of y agrees with `round` for the halfway (midpoint) cases; but then, this is a tautology. That said, you should notice that in general, the conversion of the decimal literal to binary (for `round`) will yield a rounding error. For instance, the [python documentation of `round`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round) says that `round(2.675, 2)` gives `2.67` instead of `2.68`.

Comment: I use python and javascript, but what I am looking for are properties of a "good implementation", say in standard libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes and no.
It depends on rounding modes and quality of `round()` implementation.

The compile time conversion of code `3.12` to a value depends on the *language* and *compiler* options for rounding.  Converting to the nearest [binary64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) value like `3.120000000000000106...`  (13 `0`) is *very* common.

Depending on context and language, source code like `3.12` may even convert to higher precision math as so have a value like 3.1199999999999999998959...  (16 `9`),

If the supposed function `David_Vonka_round(x, d)` (which rounds to the nearest 10<sup>-d</sup>) exist, it can slightly differ even with calls like `David_Vonka_round([digits].[digit][digit]0, 2)`.

Consider in C the below

```
// Weak rounding code
double David_Vonka_round(double x, int d) {
  pow10 = pow(10, d);
  // Note that `x * pow10` incurs a rounded product.
  // Note that `product + 0.5` incurs a rounded sum.
  long long y = (long long) (x * pow10 + 0.5);
  // A 3rd operation
  return y/pow10;
}
```

The first 2 math operations, unless done in higher precision, incur a `y` result that may differ from the expected math one.  This makes little difference with `David_Vonka_round([digits].[digit][digit]0, 2)`.  (It make an important difference with values like `David_Vonka_round([digits].[digit][digit]5, 2)`)

Those 3 math operations are also subject to the current rounding mode (nearest, up, down, toward zero, ...), which might differ from the rounding mode used during compilation.  It is that 3rd operator `/` that can then form a different value at run-time versus the compiled code.

---

In general, OP can expect the *same*, yet edge cases, variant rounding modes and weak code all contribute to differences.

Comment: So if the code above is weak, what do good implementations do?

Comment: @DavidVonka Better code does not overflow. By testing for large values which are all whole numbers or using wider math.  Scales by powers of 10 with exact math (wider type or extra code).  As `d` gets larger than 5, this task, to do well, can be surprisingly difficult to correctly handle edge cases.